# Ubuntu 18, gcc-9 failed to link tbb library for execution policy in standard library

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, std, tbb

I am trying to compile a C++17 code with g++-9 that uses execution policy in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I build and installed TBB 2020.2 with GCC-9 manually as it is not available by default for Ubuntu 18.

When I call a function that uses execution policy with parameters `std::execution::seq` or `std::exectuion::unseq` everything is fine. But when I call the same functions with parameters `std::execution::par` or `std::execution::par_unseq` it fails to link TBB. Note that the same code compiles and works without any issues in Debian 10.

My CMake is as follow and it prints the correct version of TBB (2020.2) that I want to link.

```
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
if (TBB_VERSION_MAJOR VERSION_LESS "2018")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Require tbb 2018 or higher.")
endif()
message(STATUS "TBB: ${TBB_VERSION}")
...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
```

EDIT:
Per S.M. advice on the comment using MAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE I figured out there is no linking to TBB:

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable serialize
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/serialize.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++-9  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fopenmp -ftree-vectorize -march=native -msse3 -O4 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o  -o serialize 
CMakeFiles/serialize.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'serialize' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/build-tresa'
```

Also again I printed the TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS variable in the CMake and it looks like that it is empty.
replacing TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS with TBB in target_link_libaries also didn't help.
It is very strange that CMake prints the TBB version but there are no TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS and it doesn't link any tbb shared object to executable.

Following is the compiler message messages:

```
CMakeFiles/serialize.dir/serialize.cpp.o: In function `__pstl::__par_backend::__merge_task<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, read<unsigned int, unsigned int>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)::{lambda(auto:1 const&, auto:2 const&)#1}, __pstl::__par_backend::__serial_destroy, __pstl::__par_backend::__serial_move_merge<__pstl::__par_backend::__stable_sort_task<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, {lambda(auto:1 const&, auto:2 const&)#1}, __pstl::__internal::__pattern_sort<__pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy const&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, {lambda(auto:1 const&, auto:2 const&)#1}, std::integral_constant<bool, false> >(__pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy const&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, {lambda(auto:1 const&, auto:2 const&)#1}, std::integral_constant<bool, false>, __pstl::execution::v1::parallel_policy const&<bool, true>, std::integral_constant<bool, false>)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const::{lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >, {lambda(auto:1 const&, auto:2 const&)#1})#1}>::execute()::{lambda(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >)#1}, {lambda()#1}::execute()::{lambda(std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>*, std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> > > >)#2}> >::execute()':

...

CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > nonzero<unsigned int, unsigned int>(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >)':
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x153): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_via_handler_v3(unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x1d1): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x200): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_via_handler_v3(unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x297): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x2e8): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x2f9): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x301): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x43d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE[_Z7nonzeroIjjESt6vectorIT_SaIS1_EERKS3_S0_IT0_SaIS6_EE]+0x491): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::deallocate_via_handler_v3(void*)'
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::tuple<std::vector<long long, std::allocator<long long> >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > mnge<unsigned int, unsigned int>(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._Z12multi_arangeIjjESt5tupleIJSt6vectorIxSaIxEES1_IT_SaIS4_EEEERKS6_RKS1_IT0_SaISA_EE[_Z12multi_arangeIjjESt5tupleIJSt6vectorIxSaIxEES1_IT_SaIS4_EEEERKS6_RKS1_IT0_SaISA_EE]+0x220): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'
main.cpp:(.text._Z12multi_arangeIjjESt5tupleIJSt6vectorIxSaIxEES1_IT_SaIS4_EEEERKS6_RKS1_IT0_SaISA_EE[_Z12multi_arangeIjjESt5tupleIJSt6vectorIxSaIxEES1_IT_SaIS4_EEEERKS6_RKS1_IT0_SaISA_EE]+0x41b): undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::isolate_within_arena(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&, long)'
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `_ZN3tbb15parallel_invokeIZN6__pstl13__par_backend9__upsweepIllZZNS1_10__internal17__remove_elementsIRKNS1_9execution2v115parallel_policyEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPjSt6vectorIjSaIjEEEEZNS4_19__pattern_remove_ifISA_SH_Z7nonzeroIjjESE_IT_SaISK_EERKSM_SE_IT0_SaISP_EEEUlRjE_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEESP_OSK_SP_SP_T1_T2_SU_IbLb1EEEUlPbS10_SH_E_SV_EESP_SW_SP_SP_SX_SY_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlllE1_St4plusIlEEEvSK_SK_SK_PSP_SK_SX_SY_EUlvE_ZNS3_IllS13_S15_EEvSK_SK_SK_S16_SK_SX_SY_EUlvE0_EEvRKSK_RKSP_RNS_18task_group_contextE':

...


CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6__pstl13__par_backend12__merge_taskIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt4pairIjjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESA_S6_Z8readIjjE7graph_tIT_T0_ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUlRKSD_RKSE_E_NS0_14__binary_no_opENS0_19__serial_move_mergeIZNS0_18__stable_sort_taskISA_S6_SS_ZZNS_10__internal14__pattern_sortIRKNS_9execution2v115parallel_policyESA_SS_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEvOSD_SE_SE_T1_T2_S13_IbLb1EES18_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlSA_SA_SS_E_E7executeEvEUlSA_S6_E1_ZNS1B_7executeEvEUlSA_SA_S6_E2_EEEE[_ZTIN6__pstl13__par_backend12__merge_taskIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt4pairIjjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEESA_S6_Z8readIjjE7graph_tIT_T0_ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUlRKSD_RKSE_E_NS0_14__binary_no_opENS0_19__serial_move_mergeIZNS0_18__stable_sort_taskISA_S6_SS_ZZNS_10__internal14__pattern_sortIRKNS_9execution2v115parallel_policyESA_SS_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEvOSD_SE_SE_T1_T2_S13_IbLb1EES18_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlSA_SA_SS_E_E7executeEvEUlSA_S6_E1_ZNS1B_7executeEvEUlSA_SA_S6_E2_EEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'

...


CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN3tbb10interface98internal9start_forINS_13blocked_rangeIPjEEN6__pstl13__par_backend19__parallel_for_bodyIS4_ZZNS6_10__internal17__remove_elementsIRKNS6_9execution2v115parallel_policyEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIS4_St6vectorIjSaIjEEEEZNS9_19__pattern_remove_ifISF_SL_Z7nonzeroIjjESI_IT_SaISO_EERKSQ_SI_IT0_SaIST_EEEUlRjE_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEST_OSO_ST_ST_T1_T2_SY_IbLb1EEEUlPbS14_SL_E_SZ_EEST_S10_ST_ST_S11_S12_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlS4_S4_E4_EEKNS_16auto_partitionerEEE[_ZTIN3tbb10interface98internal9start_forINS_13blocked_rangeIPjEEN6__pstl13__par_backend19__parallel_for_bodyIS4_ZZNS6_10__internal17__remove_elementsIRKNS6_9execution2v115parallel_policyEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIS4_St6vectorIjSaIjEEEEZNS9_19__pattern_remove_ifISF_SL_Z7nonzeroIjjESI_IT_SaISO_EERKSQ_SI_IT0_SaIST_EEEUlRjE_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEST_OSO_ST_ST_T1_T2_SY_IbLb1EEEUlPbS14_SL_E_SZ_EEST_S10_ST_ST_S11_S12_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlS4_S4_E4_EEKNS_16auto_partitionerEEE]+0x10): more undefined references to `typeinfo for tbb::task' follow
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3tbb10interface98internal9flag_taskE[_ZTVN3tbb10interface98internal9flag_taskE]+0x28): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3tbb8internal22parallel_invoke_helperE[_ZTVN3tbb8internal22parallel_invoke_helperE]+0x28): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN6__pstl13__par_backend18__stable_sort_taskIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt4pairIjjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEES6_Z8readIjjE7graph_tIT_T0_ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUlRKSD_RKSE_E_ZZNS_10__internal14__pattern_sortIRKNS_9execution2v115parallel_policyESA_SS_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEvOSD_SE_SE_T1_T2_S10_IbLb1EES15_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlSA_SA_SS_E_EE[_ZTVN6__pstl13__par_backend18__stable_sort_taskIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt4pairIjjESt6vectorIS5_SaIS5_EEEES6_Z8readIjjE7graph_tIT_T0_ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUlRKSD_RKSE_E_ZZNS_10__internal14__pattern_sortIRKNS_9execution2v115parallel_policyESA_SS_St17integral_constantIbLb0EEEEvOSD_SE_SE_T1_T2_S10_IbLb1EES15_ENKUlvE_clEvEUlSA_SA_SS_E_EE]+0x28): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'

...


CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3tbb8internal9final_sumINS_13blocked_rangeIlEEN6__pstl13__par_backend17__trans_scan_bodyIlZZNS4_10__internal24__pattern_transform_scanIRKNS4_9execution2v115parallel_policyEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKjSt6vectorIjSaIjEEEENSF_IPjSK_EENS7_7__no_opEjSt4plusIjESt17integral_constantIbLb1EESR_IbLb0EEEENSt9enable_ifIXntsrSt17is_floating_pointIT3_E5valueET1_E4typeEOT_T0_S13_SY_T2_SW_T4_T5_T6_SS_ENKUlvE_clEvEUllE_jSQ_ZZNS8_ISD_SL_SN_SO_jSQ_SS_ST_EES10_S12_S13_S13_SY_S14_SW_S15_S16_S17_SS_ENKS18_clEvEUllljE0_ZZNS8_ISD_SL_SN_SO_jSQ_SS_ST_EES10_S12_S13_S13_SY_S14_SW_S15_S16_S17_SS_ENKS18_clEvEUllljE1_EEEE[_ZTVN3tbb8internal9final_sumINS_13blocked_rangeIlEEN6__pstl13__par_backend17__trans_scan_bodyIlZZNS4_10__internal24__pattern_transform_scanIRKNS4_9execution2v115parallel_policyEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKjSt6vectorIjSaIjEEEENSF_IPjSK_EENS7_7__no_opEjSt4plusIjESt17integral_constantIbLb1EESR_IbLb0EEEENSt9enable_ifIXntsrSt17is_floating_pointIT3_E5valueET1_E4typeEOT_T0_S13_SY_T2_SW_T4_T5_T6_SS_ENKUlvE_clEvEUllE_jSQ_ZZNS8_ISD_SL_SN_SO_jSQ_SS_ST_EES10_S12_S13_S13_SY_S14_SW_S15_S16_S17_SS_ENKS18_clEvEUllljE0_ZZNS8_ISD_SL_SN_SO_jSQ_SS_ST_EES10_S12_S13_S13_SY_S14_SW_S15_S16_S17_SS_ENKS18_clEvEUllljE1_EEEE]+0x28): more undefined references to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'tresa' failed
make[2]: *** [tresa] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tresa.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: @S.M. I included more parts of the message. The whole error message is very very long probably multiple pages, I don't know if I should paste the whole message or not?

Comment: It won't hurt if you print `TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS` from cmake too.

Comment: @S.M. thanks I included the make command and there is no -ltbb or anything related to tbb linking. Very strange.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks look like it is empty, I manually replaced with tbb but it doesn't work. How could find_package(TBB REQUIRED) doesn't fail but the imported targes are empty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't rely on the source where you got FindTBB.cmake. `pkg-config` is more reliable.

```cmake
pkg_check_modules(TBB REQUIRED tbb>4.4) # Modify the version here

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I tried this but it fouds the old tbb 2017~U7 and it could not find the line version. 
I used include_directories("/usr/local/include") and link_directories("/usr/local/lib") but it didn't help

Comment: What is the line version?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I mean the new version that I installed to /usr/local/lib

Comment: `find /usr/local -name tbb.pc`, can this find tbb.pc?

Comment: No, but the library installed in /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so ... /usr/local/include/tbb .../usr/local/lib/cmake/tbb/TBBConfig.cmake and for some reason find_package(tbb ) shows the correct version

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find the reason why it can't link the tbb using find_package, I just linked the library manually. This way it works.

```
set(TBB_SHARED_OBJECT   "/usr/local/lib/libtbb.so")
add_library(TBBLIB SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(TBBLIB PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${TBB_SHARED_OBJECT}"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/local/include")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC TBBLIB)
```